# Add a SharePoint site to Office applications using audience targetting

Tags: sharepoint-online, my-site, office, mobile

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a Sharepoint site in the "Save As" -> "SharePoint" option with the office mobile clients (like Word) without the need to have already manually added the site through the app or via the "Connect to Office" button within a SharePoint library.

Similar to the concept of promoting sites within the User Profile using audience targeting, as it's not ideal to have to tell the users to have to manually add their team site in the application before they can save files to it.

[image]

Currently the main site collection of something.sharepoint.com shows up in the list but after hours and hours of searching I can't find any information on how to set it globally or at least add in additional sites to be visible in the menu.

Does anyone know if this is possible?